# "No such entity" ERROR in magento 2.4 admin after upgrade

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I am facing these issues into the admin during the product custom option save.

> [2019-04-29 15:00:50] main.CRITICAL: No such entity.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No
>   such entity. at
>   /var/www/html/magento2.1/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Repository.php:170)"}
>   []

Please, can you solve these issues?

Please note:- This issue is not coming in **Magento 2.1.9** version this issues coming after the upgrade.

Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be caused by some entity ids that needed to be set to 0.

When you transfer the data the insert records on these specific records are automatically generated and tend to start at 1 and not 0.

This script will help:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

accept if it helps